# Why am I unable to get error.status and error.statusText from Angular $http.get. error response?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that looks like this in an angular controller:

```
$http.get(dataUrl)
        .then(function (response) { // success getProducts
            $scope.data.products = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            $scope.data.error = error;
        });
```

dataUrl is a constant and when correct returns a list of products and everything works.
Next I wanted to test the error handling.
So I changed the dataUrl to an incorrect port number to get my data.
Now my error div shows and my content div hides.
This is correct functionality.

Here is my problem.
In my div when I show error.status, it comes back as -1.  The example I am following says it should be 404.  Also my statusText is empty or "".
Why is my error object not populating with anything.

I originally had this set up with error function as the second callback to then().
But I get the same results either way and I think catch() is cleaner as eluded to in another posted question on stack.

Comment: are you using data.error.status or error.status? because error is in $scope.data.error

Comment: You would get a 404 if you could send the request to the server, if the server received the request, looked for the resource you're asking, and didn't find it. Your situation is very different: you're sending a request to a port which no server listens to. So the connection to the server can't even succeed, and you thus can't get a 404.

Comment: Yes, this is setup following Adam Freeman's "Pro Angular JS" book.  So node.js is serving the html angular page.
The $http.get goes to a deployd server on port 5125 for the rest service.  So if I change the $http.get call to deployd rest service to use port 5000, I'm not sure what the status should be.  I guess deployd is not configured to send back server 500 error.
I could probably work it out in a real life scenario. 
For instance $http.get calls a .Net Web API and if the port or url segments are routing wrong then the server should send back server 500 or 404.

Comment: Your rest server needs to have CORS implemented since different port is considered different origin by browsers

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success
>   status and will result in the success callback being called. Any
>   response status code outside of that range is considered an error
>   status and will result in the error callback being called. Also,
>   status codes less than -1 are normalized to zero. -1 usually means the
>   request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout. Note that if the
>   response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it,
>   meaning that the outcome (success or error) will be determined by the
>   final response status code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL is: "http://localhost:5125/products" (as in:

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
.constant("dataUrl", "http://localhost:5125/products1")
.controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $http, dataUrl) {

    $scope.data = {};

    $http.get(dataUrl)
        .then(function (response) { // success getProducts
            $scope.data.products = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            $scope.data.error = error;
        });
```

});

If I change it to: "http://localhost:5000/products", the ajax request is no longer going to a webserver because it cannot find deployd serving up the products collection on port 5000. So the comment from JB Nizet is correct above.
There is no server to send back 404 or 500 so the default status must be -1 and the default statusText must be "".

But if I try this: http://localhost:5125/products1, then the ajax request finds deployd, but sends back 404 because there is no products1 collection or products1 API and so no get method for a products1 collection.  So deployd sends back 404 in this case:

[image: 404 error]

Comment: Also if you are not familiar with the deployd project, check it out here:
http://deployd.com/